# Escaping unseen ' character in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, escaping, character, quotes

```
user="some user"
host="some host"
pass="abcdefgh"
db="some db"
var1=$1
var2=$2
var3=$3
query="UPDATE table SET value = 1 , another_value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE yet_another_value = $var1"
res=$(mysql -N -s -u $user -h $host -p$pass -e "$query")
```

I pass in some parameters and plan to do things with them later on.

The error I get is that the host 'some host cannot be found. For some reason, an unseen (and unremovable) ' is inserted before the host name. I tried escaping and removing all kinds of quotes and strings.

Here's the kicker - this same exact code works in the first script but not in the second one (which accepts values from the first in parallel)

Comment: That's a nice SQL injection vulnerability you have there, adding `$1` to your query without validating it. But what is the *exact* error you are receiving? Your script may have DOS line endings that interfere with the error message.

Comment: are you looking at output from shell debugging `set -vx or set -x`? If so, the shell is "showing" where it see's the boundaries of strings by adding `'` chars. (not be best explanation). If NOT, then you'll need to include copy/paste error output into your question.

Comment: ' (1) 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'some host

Comment: you really have a space in your host name? In any case all variable usage (99% of the time) should be enclosed in dbl-quotes, i.e. `mysql -N -s -u "$user" -h "$host" -p"$pass" -e "$query"`. Good luck.

Comment: tried it, that's not the issue. and no, it's not a space, i'm just pseudocoding

Comment: This is due to DOS end-of-line characters, see [the bash tag wiki step 1](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for how to diagnose and fix it. I'm trying to find a good canonical question/answer to mark this as a duplicate

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick